# How to retrieve nested join select statement data from query

Tags: php, sql

I have the following query and am unsure of how to retrieve the 'note' from the nested join query. 
This Left join selects the latest note for this customer, but I am not sure how to echo this data...

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT note AS latestnote, timestamp, renewalid FROM renewal_note ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS n ON n.renewalid=renewal.id
```

Full Query:

```
SELECT renewal.id AS rid, renewal.personid, renewal.enddate, renewal.assettype, renewal.producttype, renewal.vrm, renewal.make, renewal.model, renewal.submodel, renewal.derivative, renewal.complete, person.forename, person.surname, person.company, appointment.id AS appid, appointment.renewalid, 
        (SELECT COUNT(complete) FROM renewal WHERE complete=1 && enddate BETWEEN '".$month_start."' AND '".$month_end."' && dealershipid='".$dealership_id."' && assettype='U' && producttype!='CH' && complete=1) AS renewedcount 
        FROM renewal 
        LEFT JOIN person ON person.id=renewal.personid 
        LEFT JOIN appointment ON appointment.renewalid=renewal.id 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT note AS latestnote, timestamp, renewalid FROM renewal_note ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1) AS n ON n.renewalid=renewal.id 
        WHERE enddate BETWEEN '".$month_start."' AND '".$month_end."' && renewal.dealershipid='".$dealership_id."' && assettype='U' && producttype NOT LIKE '%CH%' 
        ORDER BY enddate ASC
```

The Below is currently what is returned in each loop (which is working fine), and I can access as normal; $row['COLUMNNAME'].

```
rid
personid
enddate
assettype
used/new
producttype
vrm
make
model
submodel
derivative
complete
forename
surname
company
appid
renewalid
renewedcount
```

BUT I also need to be able to get the NOTE from renewal_note (the third LEFT JOIN). 
I dont have issues with normal inner joins, But I have never created a query with subqueries, so struggling to echo this data out within the php loop.

(Just to point out that the only reason I am nesting a query is that I need only the latest note for each customer to be returned.)

I have tried $row['latestnote'], (with no success) and I am sure this is definitely not the way to access this data.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**
With updates from the comments, I have tried a much more simplified query (with ALL columns included so can't miss anything out) specifically targetting the subquery:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    renewal
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        renewal_note
    ORDER BY
        TIMESTAMP
    DESC
LIMIT 1
) AS n
ON
    n.renewalid = renewal.id
```

But this still returns NULL for every column on the renewal_note.

90% of 'renewal' records have a note linked to them in the renewal_note table, but none showing.

renewal table has a unique primary key; ID.
renewal_note table links via column name: renewalid.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and an explanation of the query logic.

Comment: I have updated the question with a bit more info. Let me know if you need more :)

Comment: Add `n.latestnote` to your outer `SELECT`

Comment: Refer to subquery columns the same way as any table using it's aslias `n`  you've introduced in the query : `n.latestnote` ...

Comment: Thanks, i have now done that and shows as a coumn when running the query in phpmyadmin, but returning null...

Comment: @MaxResnikoff  We can't really comment on that without knowing what data is in your tables

Comment: Quite natural for a `LEFT JOIN` when no matching row found.

Comment: Yeah i would expect some to return null, but 18,000 records returning NULL is not right. Do i need to include n.renewalid, n.note, n.timestamp in OUTER select query aswell?

Comment: I have updated the main question with a simplified query taking your suggestions into account.

Comment: Your `LIMIT 1` in the subquery means that the joined pseudo-table only has one row in it.  Also, the `ORDER BY` is basically meaningless at that level.  You should try to describe your ultimate goal of this query in detail.  I have a feeling there's a dupe (or multiple) for this.

Comment: Ahh! ok so basically I need to return all renewal records. This is being achieved. I also need to get the lastest renewal note linked to each renewal record.
I am essentially creating a csv export will all renewal records, with their latest note.
Hence why i did a subquery as i thought this would be the only way to ORDER the notes and only get the lastest one.

Comment: One option is to join on the `renewal_note` table twice.  Once with a subquery that selects `max(id)` (hopefully you do have an id on that table) with a `GROUP BY renewalid` and then the second join is just against the full table on id from the first join.

Comment: Thanks, I think i have finally got it working thanks to your guy's help. If seems to be a fluke from what i have tested and working, i shall try your suggestion @PatrickQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have sussed this out.

Thanks to the commenters :)

Purely posting this for anyone else with similar questions/issues.

To get data from a LEFT JOIN(SELECT... statement; include the alias into the outer SELECT statement. Then you can use $row['columnname'] as normal.

LIMIT 1 on the subquery returned only 1 record for the entire query. Remove LIMIT 1 to show all results for the subquery dependant on your 'link' to the main query.

From what I have tested, ORDER BY seems to be working, but not sure if this is a fluke, or if it just sorting naturally by the primary key; ID